# Utility to recursively process text file templates and fill in placeholders

Tags: gratis, linux, text-processing

I search for a tool that is / can:

- gratis
- free from dependencies (no scripting language interpreter needed, ...)
- preferably a single binary
- run on Linux, optionally Windows
- traverse a (sub)directory structure, processing all files with a certain extension
- replace all placeholders with their value that it retrieves from a structured file (one of json, xml, key=value or CSV)
- write output to a file with identical filename, but extension removed
- preferably open source and actively maintained

The utility could be run like this:

```
pt /var/opt/configfiles .template values.properties
```

One template could be named /var/opt/configfiles/fooapp/basic.conf.template with this content:

```
Say hello to ${Name}
```

Value.properties could be structured like this:

```
Name=me
Age=18
```

After the tool finished I would have a basic.conf.

I know this can be done using sed or awk. I could also write this myself in golang but both approaches are not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't know if a ready-to-use-tool exists with your very specific needs ... But can you explain, why these approaches (some lines of scripting) are not what you're looking for ?

Comment: @RoVo two main reasons: personal preferences and the optional requirement of cross platform support. In case you can offer a script: depending on its implementation this could become an acceptable solution

Comment: Python would be cross-platform. Windows 10 can run bash script too when installed...  This can be a two-liner bash script.

Comment: @RoVo the company I work at has no python installed on Linux and I don't want to install a number of dependencies. On Windows it is unthinkable to install Python or a bash equivalent. We once had cygwin but it had to be removed and yet we have only Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This utility seems to offer much of what I am looking for: https://github.com/gomatic/renderizer

It can not do this on its own:

- traverse directories
- create output files with a name that excludes the template extension

Its value list file can only be yaml, but this is no real problem

Comment: It is acceptable, and helpful, to accept your own answer. Doing so will help others in future.